# No data pixels in raster file

Tags: python, shapefile, topojson, rasterstats

I have a TIFF file and I'm trying to use [rasterstats](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats) to get statistics of different geometries defined in a shapefile or a TopoJSON file. But I'm getting the count as 0 for all the geometries. My guess is that it's because the shapefile doesn't align properly with the raster TIFF file, maybe I'm wrong.

Below is the output of `rio info`:

```
{
    "tiled": true,
    "driver": "GTiff",
    "width": 3390,
    "nodata": 32767.0,
    "colorinterp": ["grey"],
    "lnglat": [94.65791519501956, 28.06018778470516],
    "interleave": "band",
    "crs": "+a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +lon_0=0 +no_defs +proj=sinu +units=m +x_0=0 +y_0=0",
    "blockxsize": 128,
    "dtype": "int16",
    "shape": [1348, 3390],
    "height": 1348,
    "count": 1,
    "blockysize": 128,
    "res": [231.65635826395808, 231.65635826395797],
    "bounds": [8895604.157333, 2964017.6537250075, 9680919.211847818, 3276290.424664823],
    "transform": [231.65635826395808, 0.0, 8895604.157333, 0.0, -231.65635826395797, 3276290.424664823]
}
```

And below are some of the relevant fields from the TopoJSON file:

```
{
    "type": "Topology",
    "objects": {
        "ArunachalNewDistrict-wise": {
            "type": "GeometryCollection",
            "bbox": [91.55482482910162, 26.656021118164176, 97.41516113281256, 29.463344573974723],
        "geometries": [{...}, {...}, ...],
        "arcs": [...],
        "transform": {
        "scale": [0.0005860922395950532, 0.000280760421623217],
        "translate": [91.55482482910162, 26.656021118164176]
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here's the `fio info` of the shapefile also:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "geometry": "Polygon",
        "properties": {
            "ID_0": "int:10",
            "ISO": "str:3",
            "NAME_0": "str:75",
            "ID_1": "int:10",
            "NAME_1": "str:75",
            "ID_2": "int:10",
            "NAME_2": "str:75",
            "ID_3": "int:10",
            "NAME_3": "str:75",
            "TYPE_3": "str:50",
            "ENGTYPE_3": "str:50",
            "NL_NAME_3": "str:75",
            "VARNAME_3": "str:100"
        }
    },
    "driver": "ESRI Shapefile",
    "crs_wkt": "GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_84\",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]",
    "name": "ArunachalNewDistrict-wise",
    "crs": "EPSG:4326",
    "bounds": [91.55482482910162, 26.656021118164176, 97.41516113281256, 29.463344573974723],
    "count": 15
}
```

I'm completely new to this, so most probably I'm missing something obvious. Can anybody tell me what's going on?

I can provide more info if necessary.

Comment: The only way for knowing if both layers are aligned properly is putting them together at the Map Canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way for knowing if both layers are aligned properly is putting them together at the Map Canvas. I did that (see next image), installed **rasterstats** python module with **easy_install** and, finally, ran a similar example as in your [link](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats).

```
>>>from rasterstats import zonal_stats
>>>stats = zonal_stats("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/new_polygon.shp", "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/utah_demUTM2.tif")
>>>stats
[{'count': 13004, 'max': 2738.0, 'mean': 2022.9993848046754, 'min': 1520.0}]
```

It worked in my case; as it can be watching in next image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried your suggestion, and in fact, both the layers are very far apart (I had to zoom out a lot). Is there a way to align both of them to each other? Also, the vector layer is very small compared to the raster one, so can I scale it to appropriate proportion?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Will try and update here. Thanks.